# Camel: retrieving object in activemq message

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel

Is there a way to put object in message in camel route process.

lets say i have a route

```
from("direct:send")
.process(queueProcessor)
.to(activemqEndPoint)
```

and in the queueProcessor i am putting an object in the exchange,

Now, I have a listener which listens to activemqEndPoint(queue)

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        //here i want to get the message i set it in the exchange
     }
```

Any help?? THanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trying this worked for me

```
from("direct:send")
.process(queueProcessor)
.to(parallelQueue + "?jmsMessageType=Object")
```

Answer (score 0):

sure, Camel will put an [ActiveMQObjectMessage](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/command/ActiveMQObjectMessage.html) in the queue and you can just cast the message back into your object type...

> ActiveMQObjectMessage message = (ActiveMQObjectMessage) message;
>
> MyObject myObj = (MyObject) message.getObject();