# How do I set a component parameter of type object to a route using Java DSL?

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, camel-jms

My objective is to use Camel along with its JMS component.

The route config looks like below-

```
from("jms:queue:test").to(mybean)
```

I would like to add the option of kind 'parameter' and type 'object' to this route -for example the option 'jmsMessageType'.

I saw some other posts that talks about using setProperty() on route definition but I could not find a definite answer. Options of type 'string' and numbers can be appended to the URI but not objects.

JMS has an option of taskExecutor but how can i add an instance of this to URI for routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to resolve this by adding the instances to a custom registry and using them from the endpoint URI

From official Apache Camel page

> From Camel 2.0:
>
> When configuring endpoints using URI syntax you can now refer to beans
>   in the Registry using the # notation. If the parameter value starts
>   with a # sign then Camel will lookup in the Registry for a bean of the
>   given type. For instance:
>
> file://inbox?sorter=#mySpecialFileSorter

Answer (score 1):

I think you confuse **parameter** with **option**.

**jmsMessageType** you are referring is an option of Camel's **jms** component. Each component can have many options and you can use them by appending with "?" character. For example

```
from("jms:queue:test?jmsMessageType=text").to(mybean)
```

More particular, for the jms component avalable options can be found in http://camel.apache.org/jms.html (see Common and Advanced Options sections)

Property is something different, it has nothing to do with the component, but with the **Exchange** message that is passed through the endpoints. More details are in [Passing values between processors in apache camel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330998/passing-values-between-processors-in-apache-camel)

Comment: I missed the heading in component page.  They term it as properties in the component definition. Coming back to my question, How do i set an object instance to an option in the URI?.  Update the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: So to pass an object you put **jmsMessageType=Object**. According to JMS Component documentation, you must set the object to the Exchange In body first and then send it with jms component. Maybe this is helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129983/camel-retrieving-object-in-activemq-message

Comment: It still isnt clear to me how i can set parameters of type object in an endpoint.