# Camel Component Definition : What is the difference between componentProperties and properties?

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms

We can retrieve the component json schema of a component by using the code below 
`camelContextInstance.getComponentParameterJsonSchema("jms")`

or by inspecting a component jar to find the .json file.

Inside the definition, i see there are two items - componentProperties and properties, each containing an array of elements.

**componentProperties** have elements with 'kind' attribute set as 'property' and 
**properties** have elements with 'kind' attribute set as 'parameter'.

I am aware that **properties** can be set on a route URI as parameter or path but i could not find any documentation that would shed some light into how to work with **componentProperties**.

What is the difference between these two items ?

and how do i set a **componentProperty** to a context/route?

Answer (score 1):

This json file is for tooling and not really for Camel developers to look at. If you have Camel in Action 2nd edition book it covers all about this json file in chapter 19.

For Camel end users then look at the component documentation for the component you are using, and see which option it has you can configure on component level and endpoint level:

https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components#components

Comment: What do you mean by tooling?. We are looking at a dynamic way for users to add the components they require and use them from a friendly UI. I do not have the book yet but your link gave me some clarity. Do you mind answering this question as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48536444/how-do-i-set-a-component-parameter-of-type-object-to-a-route-using-java-dsl ?